# Debugging the C++ default generated == operator using Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, operator-overloading, c++20

I'm comparing two large objects that consist of multiple collections and other objects of polymorphic types (some of them override the == operator, some not), and the == operator returns me false for the top objects that I think should be the same. Since they're large, it's hard to tell where the difference comes from. Is there a way in Visual Studio to step into the default == implementation and see where the difference is exactly?

Comment: Is this a new feature? Because I don't remember that `operator==` is generated by default.

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan It's new to C++20: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to step into it, but it should have the behavior of `return std::tie(lhs.members) == std::tie(rhs.members)`.

Comment: Do you actually overload a virtual `operator==`? That's usually a cause of problems.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the problem and it wasn't actually connected with the default generated == operator. I'll maybe leave this question in case someone would be interested into debugging the default == operator indeed.

Comment: Generally, I wouldn't expect a compiler/IDE to provide a means of debugging (e.g. stepping into) a function it defines implicitly.   If you do need to debug such an operator, you'll probably have more luck by manually defining that operator, and doing so in a way that is equivalent to the compiler-supplied default.    The problem, however, would come if a number of your base classes or members have implicitly generated comparison operators - because stepping into them with a debugger probably also won't work.